# Why is my UILabel won't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel

I have a UILabel and a UITextField that I want to show in a UIView. The textfield is shown but not the label...

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILabel *labelQuantity = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];
    labelQuantity.text = @"Quantity: ";
    [self.view addSubview: labelQuantity];

    UITextField *tfQuantity = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    tfQuantity.frame = CGRectMake(10, 120, 100, 20);
    tfQuantity.text = @"";
    [self.view addSubview: tfQuantity];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Pretty simple, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Please help, Thanks

Comment: Can you add this line labelQuantity.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; before you add this label to your view, and see can you see it?

Comment: if you are trying on `iOS 7` with `navigationBar` then make it origin y around 70. And if you not gone trough iOS 7 UI, then please first walk through it https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1

Comment: I tried it but no yellow label appears

Comment: Thanks Bhumeshwer katre it worked just fine!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I can see why it will not appear is because of this line:

```
UILabel *labelQuantity = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20)];
```

Your x and y positions are going to appear behind your `UINavigationBar` and the height is to short to make it appear below it.

This is assuming you are using a `UINavigationBar`.

I would redo this to:

```
 UILabel *labelQuantity = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 64, 300, 20)];
```

This will drop it below the `UINavigationBar`